# while loop debugging in netlogo

Tags: debugging, while-loop, netlogo

I am having trouble understanding an error emerging from two consecutive while loops in a net logo project.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;; Global variables ;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

globals [it]              

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;; Breedin agents ;;; 
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

breed [houses house]
breed [firms firm]

;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;; Setup ;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  create-firms F
  create-houses H          

  ;; sets position of the firms in the space for better visualisation

     set it 0
  while [it < F ]
  [ask firm it [
      set color yellow
      set heading it * 360 / F
      fd 5 
      ]  
  set it it + 1
  ]

;; sets position of the households in the space for better visualisation  

  set it 0
  while [it < H ]
  [ask house it [
      set color yellow
      set heading it * 360 / H
      fd 15
      ]    
  set it it + 1
  ]
```

When I run the above code I get an error message

```
firm 0 is not a HOUSE
error while observer running HOUSE
  called by procedure SETUP
  called by Button 'Setup'
```

pointing at `house it` in the code.

Notice that when I only run the first while loop, everything works fine.

I guess there is something I do not understand in the use of while loops in net logo.

- Why does the second while loop seem to consider that I am calling firms although I asked to call houses?
- Is there a better way to implement while loops in net logo?

Many thanks in advance for you help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What's happening?

`who` numbers in NetLogo are assigned *from the same sequence* for all turtles, independently of their breeds. If you do:

```
create-firms 1
create-houses 1
```

Then you will have `firm 0` and `house 1`, which you could also address as turtles. For example, in the command center:

```
observer> show turtle 0
observer: (firm 0)
observer> show turtle 1
observer: (house 1)
```

It makes sense to have unique identifiers like that, because the breed of a turtle is a very transient thing. It can be changed:

```
observer> ask firm 0 [ set breed houses ]
observer> show turtle 0
observer: (house 0)
```

The turtle has kept its `who` number despite the change of breed.

> Why does the second while loop seem to consider that I am calling firms although I asked to call houses?

What you are doing is the equivalent of taking **`turtle`** `0` (which is a firm) and trying to *cast* it to a house. This is why NetLogo complains that `firm 0` is not a house.

### A better way to do it

> Is there a better way to implement while loops in net logo?

Yes: don't use `while`! More seriously: using `while` is most often unnecessary. There is usually a better way to do things.

Also, in general, **don't use `who` numbers for anything**. If you want to deal with many turtles at once, use a turtle set. If you want to keep track of a turtle, store the reference to it directly (e.g., `set my-firm one-of firms`). If you find yourself wanting to use the `who` number, take a step back and rethink about your problem: there is almost certainly another way.

You want to do something with all your houses? Just ask them!

```
ask houses [
  set color yellow
  fd 15
]
```

There is one thing that the snippet above does not address, however: your requirement for evenly spaced turtles. But you can achieve this by using the [`create-ordered-<breeds>`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#create-ordered-turtles) to create your turtles. With it, your entire `setup` becomes:

```
clear-all
create-ordered-firms F [
  set color yellow
  fd 15
]
create-ordered-houses H [
  set color yellow
  fd 15
]
```

### But what if you really need an index?

But what if `create-ordered-<breeds>` did not exist, or if you wanted to do something similar that required some sort of index? You still don't need `while`: a combination of [`foreach`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#foreach) and [`n-values`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#n-values) will get you there:

```
create-houses H
(foreach sort houses n-values H [ ? * 360 / H ] [
  ask ?1 [
    set color yellow
    set heading ?2
    fd 15
  ]
])
```

(We use [`sort`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#sort) to turn the `houses` turtle set into a list, but `[self] of houses` works as well if you want them shuffled.)

That code may look weird at first, but it's actually a pretty common and useful pattern in NetLogo. It "zips" the thing you want to act on with the index that you want to assign to it. It also has a few nice advantages over a while loop: no "off by one" errors, no extra variable and no risk of forgetting to increment the counter or to accidentally mutate it.

Comment: Many thanks @Nicolas Payette. Very clear and insightful answer.